Integration involving bessel functions
I want to (efficiently) integrate a function of the form
$$
\int_0^a f(r) J_1(kr) \, dr,
$$
where $f$ is some function which involves trigonometric functions and where I do not always have $a,k\gg 1$.
What is the best approach to perform this integral?
I've tried using Scipy's quad to evaluate it, but it has given me convergence problems. I do not necessarily need to use python, but I'd prefer to. In particular, any approach compatible with JAX would be highly appreciated, as I need to perform this integral over a (large) grid.
Edit: My particular case involves the function $f(r) = \dfrac{\sin\left(\omega\sqrt{r^2 + b^2} - \omega a\right)}{\sqrt{r^2 + b^2}}$, which I integrate over a 3D grid with changing $a, b, k$.

What does "it has given me convergence problems" mean in practice? How have you tried to interpret or fix these problems?

Well, quad is giving me a message telling me that the integral is "not converging as it might be divergent or slowly convergent". I have tried splitting the integration interval, which seemed to aliviate some of the problem (for certain $a,k$ I wouldn't get that warning). I also tried to use a weighted integral using the sin/cos weights (this is because of the shape of $f$). This didn't work. What I can say for sure is that my end result doesn't look like what I expected!

I mean, the message isn't wrong: $J_1(r)/r$ does convergence pretty slowly to zero, and so you will end up with slow convergence if $a\gg 1$ or $k\gg 1$. That is a mathematical issue you need to address, not one related to any specific implementation of quadrature.

@WolfgangBangerth Yes, that is definitely a big part of the problem.

Julia seems to deal with this quite well. (although more specifics in the question would obviously help to know if this is an appropriate benchmark).
using Bessels, QuadGK
g(r) = cos(r)*besselj1(1000*r)/r
julia> @time quadgk(g, 0, 5) # integrate from 0 to 5
  0.001082 seconds (8 allocations: 29.328 KiB)
(0.9999998755689227, 1.4806691727474335e-8)
julia> @time quadgk(g, 0, 100) # integrate from 0 to 100
  0.017314 seconds (16 allocations: 1.274 MiB)
(0.9999995326993543, 1.4900311042581983e-8)

for evaluating this multiple times over a grid, if all you're changing is a, it might be worth caching the value for a range of a, so that you can use shorter integrals.

Thank you for your reply! I have updated the question with the specifics.
